# Integrability condition implies boundedness and limit is zero

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-continuity

I'm having trouble with the following problem.

> Suppose that $f$ is a uniformly continuous function on $(0,\infty)$ with derivative $f^\prime(x)$ satisfying,
>
> $$ \int_0^\infty xf^2(x)dx < \infty, \;\;\;\;\;\;\int_0^\infty x^3(f^\prime(x))^2dx < \infty$$
>
> Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}xf(x) = 0$.

I tried to prove by contradiction. I assumed that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ and a sequence $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ such that $|x_nf(x_n)| > \epsilon$ for all $n$. Using uniform continuity, I showed that,

$$ \int_{x_n-\delta}^{x_n+\delta}xf(x)dx > \epsilon\delta $$

where $\delta$ is the modulus of continuity. Therefore, $$ \int_0^\infty xf(x)dx \geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\int_{x_n-\delta}^{x_n+\delta}xf(x)dx > \infty $$

My initial reasoning for using this approach was to hopefully use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to arrive at the contradiction,

$$ \int_0^\infty xf(x)dx \leq \left(\int_0^\infty xf^2(x)dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^\infty xdx\right)^{1/2} $$

However, obviously the second integral is not finite so this approach probably will not work. Is there a slight modification I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Use integration by parts

$$\int_a^b x f^2(x) \, dx  = \left.\frac{1}{2}(x f(x))^2\right|_a^b - \int_a^b x^2 f(x) f'(x) \, dx$$

and 
$$\left|\int_a^b x^2 f(x) f'(x) \, dx  \right| \leqslant \left(\int_a^b x f^2(x) \, dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_a^b x^3 (f'(x))^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Ah, clear and concise. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnDoe1234: Nice question. Good try.

Comment: Actually, I'm not clear as to why the the above will force the limit to be 0? We know that it should be finite from the above.

Comment: Uniform continuity allows $f$ to be extended continuously at $x =0$.

Comment: Since we know $xf^2$ is integrable and show $xff'$ is integrable the limit of $x^2|f(x)|^2$ as $x \to \infty$ exists. Could it not be $0$?

Comment: If $x^2f^2(x) \to L \neq 0$ as $x \to \infty$ then $xf^2(x) \sim L/x$ would not be integrable.

Comment: Ah, okay thank you very much.